# Event related recursion on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, events

Lets say we have a function called `doSomething()`;

Inside this function I am declaring an object called `dispatcher`.

`dispatcher` has a function that works asynchronously and omits an `'end'` event when its finished.

So the code looks like this:

```
const doSomething = () => {
    const dispatcher = someObject.function.thatReturnsDispatcher();
}
```

So this `doSomething()` function is not totally useless and actually does so much more than just assigning a single variable and I want this `dispatcher` to do the same stuff that `doSomething()`
does whenever its asynchronous function ends. So I do something like this:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
    //important stuff above

    const dispatcher = someObject.function.thatReturnsDispatcher();
    dispatcher.on('end' , () => {
        doSomething();
    });

    //important stuff below
}
```

and it works!

But I wonder one thing:

When it is called, does the function `doSomething()` works recursively **or** does the function end and node saves the `discpatcher.on('end')` function and calls it whenever an `end` event omits?

Comment: It's not recursive per-se. It won't cause a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error, if that's your question. Because it's used in an asynchronous callback, the stack can be freed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both.

There is no doubt that `doSomething` is recursively called (the next call to `doSomething` happens from within the current `doSomething` call).

And, depending on what are you doing in the commented out stuff, `doSomething` will probably end before the dispatcher callback gets called, `dispatcher.on` registers the callback to be called when the thing ends no matter whether `doSomething` ends or not.